# Looking for an elegant way to construct this tensor-product-ish list

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors

I would like to make the following matrix:

```
{
  {{1, 13}, {1, 14}, {1, 15}, {1, 16}, {2, 13}, {2, 14}, {2, 15},{2, 16}, ..., 
   {32, 13}, {32, 14}, {32, 15}, {32, 16}},
  {{1, 9}, {1, 10}, {1, 11}, {1, 12}, {2, 9}, {2, 10}, {2, 11}, {2, 12}, ..., 
   {32, 9}, {32, 10}, {32, 11}, {32, 12}},
   ...
  {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3},{2, 4}, ..., 
   {32, 1}, {32, 2}, {32, 3}, {32, 4}}
}
```

I'd like to make this out of these two things:

```
A = {Range[13, 16], Range[9, 12], Range[5, 8], Range[4]}
```

and

```
B = Range[32]
```

In other words, I'd like to glue copies of `A` all in a row with each entry indexed by `B`.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Outer[List, B, #] & /@ A
```

Comment: This is very nice.  I should add that it does fall slightly short of my desired form, but the gap can be easily closed by `Flatten[#,1]&/@(Outer[List,B,#]&/@A)`.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I like this one a little better: `Flatten[Outer[List, B, A], {{2}, {1, 3}, {4}}]`

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yes, those mysterious arguments of `Flatten` are cool if you get them to work. But I honestly would have chosen Alexander's approach (if I had noticed the different nesting depth in the first place)... One could also do this with `Transpose`, I think.

Comment: Yes, yours is equivalent to `Transpose@Outer[List, B, A]`. Since `Transpose` is equivalent to `Transpose[..., {2, 1}]` and `Flatten[..., {{2}, {1}}]`, and given that he wanted to flatten the two middle levels together, that got me from yours to what I posted above. Actually, it can be written as `Flatten[Outer[List, B, A], {{2}, {1, 3}}]`, although the fact that trailing unaltered levels can freely be omitted from the second argument doesn't seem to be documented.

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility is  `Distribute`

```
soln = Distribute[{B, #}, List] & /@ A
```

And

```
soln == (Flatten[#, 1] & /@ (Outer[List, B, #] & /@ A)) == 
Flatten[Outer[List, B, A], {{2}, {1, 3}, {4}}]
```

=> True

**Edit**

Yet another possibility is  `Tuples`

(A little  surprising to my mind that this one works)

```
Tuples[{B, #}] & /@ A
```

And

```
(Tuples[{B, #}] & /@ A) == soln
```

=> True

Comment: Very nice (+1).

Comment: `Tuples` clearly seems the best way to go; it's also an order of magnitude faster than other options on most data.  You should IMHO add timings to your answer in support of the superiority of your last method; if you don't have time I can do it if you'd like.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard.  No time at the moment but by all means add/edit anything you want.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is not at all elegant as @Jens but this is one more long way to do it.
First we establish interaction between both lists as,

```
Table[{B[[k]], A[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, Length[A]}, {j, 1, 
  Length[A[[i]]]}, {k, 1, Length[B]}]
```

After that we flatten the array as,

```
arr = ArrayFlatten[%]
```

Than again partition the sublists using Table as,

```
Table[Partition[arr[[i]], 2], {i, 1, Length[arr]}]
```

This shall answer your question as well probly.