# Fast two dimensional version of Range[]

Tags: performance-tuning

I have need of a two dimensional version of `Range[]`. I have a few ideas of varying speeds, and I was wondering if anyone knew a better way to do this.

```
rangeX=2000;evaluatedRangeX=Range[rangeX];
rangeY=2000;evaluatedRangeY=Range[rangeY];
speed1=First[AbsoluteTiming[test1=Table[{y,x},{y,rangeY},{x,rangeX}];]];
speed2=First[AbsoluteTiming[test2=Outer[{#1,#2}&,evaluatedRangeY,evaluatedRangeX];]];
speed3=First[AbsoluteTiming[test3=Array[{#1,#2}&,{rangeY,rangeX}];]];
speed4=First[AbsoluteTiming[
 test4=Table[Transpose[{ConstantArray[y,rangeX],evaluatedRangeX}],{y,rangeY}];]];
speed5=First[AbsoluteTiming[Range[rangeX*rangeY];]];
test1==test2==test3==test4
{speed1,speed2,speed3,speed4,speed5}
```

With results:

```
True
{2.813062, 2.179700, 0.575586, 0.082393, 0.019547}
```

So my best effort is still four times slower than using `Range[]` to make a one dimensional range of the same size, which seems like a reasonable lower bound. Can anyone suggest a better way?

Comment: `Partition[Tuples[{evaluatedRangeY,evaluatedRangeX}], rangeX]` Seems quite quick

Comment: `Outer[List, evaluatedRangeY, evaluatedRangeX]`

Comment: Nice one @SimonWoods! Best so far at `0.025749`.

Comment: I don't get equal `test*` results when `rangeX = 3` and `rangeY = 2`.  Typo somewhere?

Comment: That's what I get for only testing with `rangeX=rangeY` . Typos indeed. Should be fixed.

Comment: This is contained in the question: [Looking for an elegant way to construct this tensor-product-ish list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27700/looking-for-an-elegant-way-to-construct-this-tensor-product-ish-list)